# Check after someone

Tags: prepositions

Is it "check **after** someone"? As in

> I need to check **after** him lest the job is done wrong.

By "check after him" I hoped to say "check if the job he has done is done right"

Comment: Why was it closed? What details are missing?

Answer (score 3):

In UK English you would most probably say

> I need to check that he has done the job properly.

or

> I need to check in case he has done the job wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you mean "Check on him",  though just "check him" is probably fine, so the preposition is redundant, and you could probably use "after". At least in the kind of fairly informal context that I imagine this to be.

The use of "lest" is odd and anachronistic.  The word "lest" is rarely used. It's archaic or formal.

Comment: "Check on him" implies he is still doing it (as does "check him"). By "check after him" I hoped to say "check if the job he has done is done right". Any more suggestions?

Comment: If the work is finished, you need to check the _work_ and not the worker.